# datatables.net column width in % and px

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

i am using datatables.net and need to have some columns with fixed width and others to divide the remaning space in %

this is my code

```
{ "sName": "ragsoc_denom", "sWidth": "100%"},
{ "sName": "piva", "sWidth": "80px"},
{ "sName": "telefono", "sWidth": "100px"},
{ "sName": "indirizzo", "sWidth": "100px"},
{ "sName": "cap", "sWidth": "50px"},
{ "sName": "citta", "sWidth": "50px"},
{ "sName": "id", "sWidth": "70px"}
```

but it doesn't work, the percentage tables take all available space and the fixed width ones get streched to minimum

Comment: Would you please post any code which wraps around your table, any div tags etc

Comment: You may want to try adding "sClass": "someclass" to the fixed columns, then in your style sheet set the class to !important and set their width from your style sheet instead of using sWidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not care how the remaining % is dispersed you could leave it up to datatables by setting the remaining sWidths to null.

If you do care how the remaining % are split up can you do this dynamically at runtime by taking the total static px (in this example 450px) subtract it from the current width of the table and then use that as a guide to determine the remaining percentages for the columns.

For example if i had a datatable that was 1000px

1000 - 450 = 550

I want a column which is 10% of the remaining

550px of 1000px = 55% left so 10% of 55% = 5.5%

Comment: i already found the swidth null trick, but yeah i guess there is no other way

Answer (score 3):

Try setting "bAutoWidth": false,

Comment: I have one table setup like below. First column has 10px width because it contains a checkbox. I would check to see if your table header or footer columns are affecting the size of the columns you set width on. Also maybe if your table wrapper is say 650px. To set a px size on ragsoc_denom column equal to remainder after adding other columns they are 450px so maybe set other column to 200px

oTable7 = $('#pages').dataTable( {
"sDom":'t<"bottom"filp><"clear">',
"bAutoWidth": false,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"aoColumns": [ 
{ "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "10px" },
null,
null,
null,

Answer (score 0):

If the code listed for the initial question is still being used, I'm thinking the problem may have something to do with the first column being set to take up 100% of the space...